# Allowing a Java method to call methods of a parameter object's subclass?

Tags: java

I'm working on a small university assignment. Being tired of writing three lines of code to add buttons I wrote a small utility function:

```
private JButton addButton(Container container, String text) {

    JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    container.add(button);

    return button;
}
```

Then of course came along the utility method to add textFields:

```
private JTextField addInput(Container container, int width) {

    JTextField input = new JTextField(width);
    input.addActionListener(this);
    container.add(input);

    return input;
}
```

As you can see, they are almost identical. So I tried to reduce the number of lines by having an all powerful method that would add anything to any other thing.

```
private Component addComponent(Container container, Component component) {

    component.addActionListener(this);
    container.add(component);

    return component;
}
```

Now, I must admit that I'm starting to think maybe these ultra small utility functions are a bit absurd.

However, regardless, my all powerful `addComponent` method didn't work. Instead complaining that `Component`'s don't have `ActionListeners`.

The only way I can see around this is having a `MyJButton` and `MyJTextField` both of which inherit from `MyComponent` which has an `addActionListener` method. The original goal of simplicity and removing repetition being thrown out the window?

**How can/should this be done? I'm new to Java and the strictly typed stuff!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that your current approach (a bunch of similar helper methods) is as good as you'll get.

Some things are inelegant, and there's not much you can do about it.

The risk of trying to combine the methods (along the lines of @leonbloy's answer) is that you replace static type safety with runtime type safety; i.e. `ClassCastExceptions` when a typecast fails ... or worse.

---

From a linguistic perspective, what is needed is a way for an application to "decorate" an existing class hierarchy with an extra method (or methods), and have the methods called by polymorphic dispatching, much as you do with ordinary instance methods.

This can be simulated using the Decorator pattern, but it requires some fairly heavyweight infrastructure ... if the class hierarchy doesn't have the hooks to support the pattern built in.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches. If you know for sure that your method `addComponent` will only act on `JTextField` and `JButton` parameters, you can do explicit casts

```
 if (component instanceof JButton){
  ((JButton)component).addActionListener(this); 
 }
 else if (component instanceof JTextField){
  ((JTextField)component).addActionListener(this);
 }
```

Not very elegant, not very good practice, but it might suffice in your scenario.

If you want to invoke `addActionListener` if the `Component` has that method, you can use reflection - but I suspect this would be overkill for your goal.

PS: In case its more clear to you, this would be equivalent to the second line:

```
  JButton button = (JButton)component; // explicit cast -we know for sure that this is a JButton 
  button.addActionListener(this);
```

Comment: This would be a bad place to use reflection.  You'd simply be doing the same thing in a (probably) less efficient and (definitely) more fragile way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there isn't an interface that exposes the

```
addActionListener(ActionListener l)
```

if there were, you could do

```
public <T extends Component & ActionListenable> Component addComponent(Container container, T component) {

    component.addActionListener(this);
    container.add(component);

    return component;
}
```

Assuming that the faux ActionListenable is the aforementioned interface.